# Adding tap gesture to the second part of string after full stop iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I have a label on a UIView. The text of the label is "All 100 entities selected. Select all from server" I know how to handle a tap gesture on the whole label. However, in this case, I need the tap gesture to work only if the user taps on 'Select all from server' part of the string. The portion of the string before and after the full stop can be of variable length.

I have come across TTTAttributedString but am wondering whether its usage is appropriate for my problem.

Comment: I think TTTAttributedLabel will be appropriate component for your task. you need to add link to TTTAttributedLabel, and respond to link selection in it's delegate method (attributedLabel:didSelectLinkWithTextCheckingResult:)

Comment: However maybe it's better to leave All 100 entities selected text as UILabel and add second part 'Select all from server' as UIButton component. It would be much simpler and clearer solution

Comment: Yes I agree that using a button would be easier, but since the text can be variable, it'll pose problems with the auto layout constraints I am using. I have created the custom view using TTTAttributedLabel.The part I was worried about works fine but I have run into another problem. Posting that in a separate question.